# Code will never be executed for bool in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Having error code will never be executed

```
-(BOOL)hasInternet {

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStats = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (internetStats == NotReachable) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

    NSLog(@"Internet is %d", hasInternet);
}
```

Comment: It can never execute your `NSLog` statement, because that's after your `return` statements. Either log your status before you return, or log the status where you called `hasInternet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given error implies **will never be executed**
 NSLog(@"Internet is %d", hasInternet); statement can not be executed, because **before executing this statement you are returning from the method hasInternet** either from the if or else block, **If you want to log message** you should write the statement before returning from the method.